# Migration : Incompatibility in data. Source document: eav_attribute_group

Tags: migration, magento2.3, data-migration-tool, eav-attributes

I face issue when migrate from Magento 1 to Magento 2.3

> Incompatibility in data. Source document: eav_attribute_group. Field: attribute_group_name. Error: The product attribute set "Testing" does not contain all required attribute group names "General, Prices, Design, Images"

**Note :** I created Testing Attribute set and add above 4 attribute group names in that attribute set. Still, it's not solve.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you get any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday I got the same issue and to fix above issue you need to edit Attribute Set `Testing` and add missing `attribute group names`. i.e General, Prices, Design, Images

If you edit Attribute Set `Testing`, you will find required attribute group name is missing.

> Please make sure you attribute set having required `attribute group names`.

Just create empty group name and it will work!

Hope above will help!

Comment: I created Testing attribute set and add attribute group name in that set. But, still it's not solve. Can you please help me?

Comment: after changes error changed Or Same ?

Comment: Yes. same error.

Comment: try bin/magento migrate:data --reset, after adding above attribute set and group.-reset should work

Comment: Not working....

Answer (score 0):

It is due to you have rename default attribute group (General, Prices, Design, Images) to something else in your magento 1 website.

Or in your magento1 (General, Prices, Design, Images) where renamed. then you need revert its names back.

Comment: I can't able to revert names back. Without changing in Magento 1 is there any solution available?

Comment: Names of attribute groups in magento1 should be the same as in magento2

Comment: Or you can try rename this attribute groups in magento2 that they will be the same as in m1

Comment: Did it help to you?

Comment: No any luck :( ..